# Why does getSubImage of a large image fix blank pixels?

Tags: bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have a program that creates a sprite sheet from a folder of images.  Here is the code:

```
int length = 1000;
BufferedImage sheet = new BufferedImage(1280*length/3, 720/3, 
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    String path = i+".jpg";
    try {
        load = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
        sheet.getGraphics().drawImage(load, (i%100)*1280/3, (i/100)*720/3, null);
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load "+path);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
try {
    ImageIO.write(sheet, "jpg", new File("spriteSheet"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to write spriteSheet.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
this.stop();
```

This mostly worked, but half of the 2nd to last row and the entire last row were being saved as a solid canvas of tan-colored pixels.  To see if the individual images being converted into the sprite sheet were the issue I added this code right after drawing the image to the sheet:

```
BufferedImage current = sheet.getSubimage((i%100)*1280/3, (i/100)*720/3, 1280/3, 720/3);
render(current);
```

and the render method is:

```
public void render(BufferedImage image) {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

And after this code was added the sheet was being completely drawn without any tan-colored pixels.  Why did getting a sub-image of the sheet while writing it seem to fix this issue?

Edit:  Okay so the problem is not completely fixed.  Sometimes it still draws the bottom row as tan-colored pixels.  If I run the program again it will usually fix it though.  Sometimes it does it the 1st time, sometimes the 2nd, sometimes it takes 3 runs...

Comment: Does changing the format from JPEG to PNG change this behavior? Could be a JPEG artifact...

Comment: I have no idea what this was, but now it doesn't happen anymore (files still JPEG).  The only thing I can think of that happened between this bug occuring and it not occuring is my OS had a big update.